# Transition effect has different behaviour on different Android

Tags: android, transition

I have transition effect like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
<shape
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient android:startColor="#ffff77" android:centerColor="#fdfdee" 
android:endColor="#cccc00"
    android:angle="-90" />
    <corners android:radius="7px"></corners>            
</shape>
 </item>  
 <item>
 <shape 
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient android:startColor="#f55" android:centerColor="#eee" 
android:endColor="#f00"
    android:angle="-90" />      
</shape>
</item> 
</transition>
```

It works correctly on Android 2.2, 2.3, 4.0. Recently, I've bought Galaxy S4 with Android 4.2.2. I tried to run this transition effect on it and I noticed that it works improperly. Sometimes there was no color changing at all. Although, some elements was changing their color, they had different color from those which were running on Android 2.3. Take a look at picture:

Result in Android 4.2.2

[image]

[image]

Relust in Android 2.3

[image]

[image]

As you can see the tabs have different colors. How to fix this problem? Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It seems post API 17 (Android 4.2), a setting in the developer options of certain devices (mainly Samsung Galaxy) automatically resets itself - it could be due to this.

If you go into Settings > Developer Options on your device, and look for an option called '**Transition Animation Scale**' - if this is set to '**Animation Off**', change it to '**Animation Scale 1x**'.

Comment: Users don't care about going to `Developer Console`. I have to fix it programmatically.